# Assembly manager - All probing URLs attempted and failed

Tags: asp.net

I have a VirtualMerchant project which is dependent on SysAuto.Web.Payment project.
Both VirtualMerchant and the Web.Payment project, once built, are version 2.0.1
However, from the assembly binding log viewer, we can see that the assembly loader is looking for SysAuto.Web.Payment Version=2.0.0.0

I have spent hours trying to figure out why it is looking for version 2.0.0 instead of going with 2.0.1. Or alternatively, why would the (vs 2013 ide) build would do a version 2.0.1, instead of a 2.0.0.
How am I saying these numbers. I click on the references, from the VirtualMerchant project, then click on the Web.Payment project, and on the properties, it shows version 2.0.0. Then when I go to the debug folder, reach the Web.Payment project dll, right click to Details, it shows 2.0.1.

Now, I do not even know if I am interpreting the issue correctly based on the log below.

It is hard for me to interpret this.

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (5/3/2021 @ 3:56:48 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/develop/gitrepos/CDT/egovern/SysAuto.egovern.Web/Source/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\develop\gitrepos\CDT\egovern\SysAuto.egovern.Web\Source\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Users\sakg\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1df0e490
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Users\sakg\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1df0e490
LOG: AppName = 68c4ab8d
Calling assembly : SysAuto.Web.Payment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\develop\gitrepos\CDT\egovern\SysAuto.egovern.Web\Source\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\sakg\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/sakg/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/1df0e490/68c4ab8d/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/sakg/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/1df0e490/68c4ab8d/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/gitrepos/CDT/egovern/SysAuto.egovern.Web/Source/bin/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/gitrepos/CDT/egovern/SysAuto.egovern.Web/Source/bin/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/sakg/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/1df0e490/68c4ab8d/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/sakg/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/1df0e490/68c4ab8d/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/gitrepos/CDT/egovern/SysAuto.egovern.Web/Source/bin/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/gitrepos/CDT/egovern/SysAuto.egovern.Web/Source/bin/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant/com.clairs.providers.VirtualMerchant.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```